# Normalizer of a transitive subgroup in the symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G$ be a finie group, and $H$ be a core-free subgroup of $G$ (that is to say, there is no nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$). Denote by $\Omega$ the set of right cosets of $H$ in $G$. Then $G$ is a transitive permutation group on $\Omega$. Let $N$ be the normalizer of $G$ in $Sym(\Omega)$. Then when does $N$ lie in $Alt(\Omega)$?

We may first focus on a special case when $H=1$. That is to ask if there is some classification (or a good characterization of the group structure) for groups $G$ with $Hol(G)$ consisting only of even permutations. To ensure $Hol(G)$ consists only of even permutations, a necessary condition is that $G$ acting on itself by right multiplication does not contain odd permutations, which is equivelant to that the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ is not non-trivial cyclic.

Comment: I can't imagine what sort of answer you are expecting to a question like that.

Comment: @DerekHolt This may be a too wide question. Let me first focus on a special case when H=1. That is to ask is there some classification for groups $G$ with $Hol(G)$ consisting of even permutations?

Comment: @DerekHolt To ensure that G acting on itself by right multiplication does not contain odd permutations, we need exactly that the Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$ is not non-trivial cyclic. For exmaple, consider $G=C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: You are right - I have deleted my previous comment, but I am afraid I cannot think of anything helpful to say about this. You might need to restrict your question further.